# Facebook authorization

Tags: php, facebook

I have developed an moderation app in php through which I moderate all the posts and comments. I also have an option to post a POST on facebook fan page wall. But when I try to do so an exception is been thrown that says "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

Any help on this!!! Thanks

**Update**

Here I ask for the permissions from user to POST through fan page

```
$hasPermission = $facebook->api_client->call_method('Users.hasAppPermission',array('ext_perm'=>'publish_stream', 'uid'=>$fbuid));
        $hasPermission_offline = $facebook->api_client->call_method('Users.hasAppPermission',array('ext_perm'=>'offline_access', 'uid'=>$fbuid));
```

Here I try to publish the post on wall of the page

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($rowdata['posttext'])),$objAttachment, '', $objfbpharmawall->pageid, $uid)
```

Comment: 1)is the user a fan of the page? 2)do you have a privacy not allowing users to post to the page? 3)share some code!

Comment: Yes user is fan of the page and there is no privacy instead I ask for the permissions from the user before posting a post on a wall.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are ***asking*** for a permission or ***checking*** for a certain permission!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take extended permissions first :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Btw do not post anything without user approval even if you have taken the extended permission. That is against Facebook policy and they might block your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Before a user posts on a wall I do ask for the extended permission like publish_stream, basic info and offline_access. Do you think I need to the permissions apart from this.